# joining two tables to be bound on a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I was getting confused on how to build the SQL query when it come to joining two tables so that I could bind them later to a gridview.

Basically I have two tables,

```
tablename: family
 __________________________
|Status |lastName|firstName|
|-------|--------|---------|
|1      |11      |111      |
|2      |22      |222      |
|3      |33      |333      |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            +

tablename: familyStatus
 _____________________
|id        | Notes    |
|----------|----------|
|1         | 1111     |
|2         | 2222     |
|3         | 3333     |
'''''''''''''''''''''''

           =

Joined-tables: family+familyStatus [this is what i want]
 ____________________________
|firstName | lastName |Notes |
|----------|----------|------|
|111       | 11       |1111  |
|222       | 22       |2222  |
|333       | 33       |3333  |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

what your seeing here is that the **Status** from table **family** and **id** from **familyStatus** is the same key, status and id will be hidden on the gridview.

```
Lets just assume for now that this is how i get the family table.

SELECT Status, firstName, lastName
FROM family
WHERE firstName= @fN
AND lastName = @lN
```

What do I need to add here so that the Notes from family table also gets joined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A join:

```
SELECT F.firstName, F.lastName, FS.Notes
FROM family F
INNER JOIN familyStatus FS
    ON F.[Status] = FS.id
WHERE F.firstName= @fN
AND F.lastName = @lN
```

Comment: what is FS and F? 
i would like to avoid editing the tables in db

Comment: @Mana I didn't edit the tables at all, I'm just using table aliases, to identify the table of each column.

Comment: oki, havn't used it before, will it workin in my mssql query ?

Comment: @Mana Yes, it will. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: oki, thanks, will try this tomorrow early morning, on my way home now, chears, thanks. will comment if im stuck.

Comment: thanks for your help, had to modify it a bit, but its now working.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Status foreign key to the familyStatus table and try the following:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, Notes
FROM family JOIN familyStatus
ON family.Status =  familyStatus.Status
WHERE firstName= @fN
AND lastName = @lN
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick answer, i would really like to avoid tempering with the tables.

Comment: You typically can't guarantee that the keys in both tables will stay in synch and a foreign key is the recommended way to join two tables.